# ¿Que iría en mi BASE_URL en android studio?

Tags: android, url, postman, sharedpreferences

**Hola, estoy haciendo una consulta a una cuenta corriente.
En la imagen de abajo, son los datos que me proporciona mi jefe para ejecutarlo.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**y acá al ponerlo en Postman, tengo que usar otro link**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Pero los datos que quiero son estos**[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**mi pregunta es: que URL debo poner en Android studio?**

`public class RetroClass {

```
    private static final String BASEURL="http://qcsys.servehttp.com:922/jderest/";
    private static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance()
    {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();


        return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASEURL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();


    }

    public static APIService getAPIService()
    {
        return getRetrofitInstance().create(APIService.class);
    }


}
```

**y para el token tambien estoy confundido, quiero guardarlo en un sharedpreferences, ya que tengo entendido que tiene poca vida y hay que usarlo para poder exraer los datos.**

`

public class TokenManager {

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private Context context;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private int Mode = 0;
private static  final String REF_NAME="TokenManager";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "username";
public static final String KEY_JWT_TOKEN="jwttokenname";

public TokenManager(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(REF_NAME,Mode);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

}



public void createLoginSession(String username , String jwttokenname)
{
    editor.putString(KEY_NAME,username);
    editor.putString(KEY_JWT_TOKEN,jwttokenname);
    editor.commit();



}


public void logOUT()
{

}
```

}

**Les dejo mi MainActivity y las demas solapas si en un futuro le pasa a alguien lo mismo y quiere comparar información**.

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText username,userpass;
private Button senddata;
private TokenManager tokenManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    userpass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userpass);
    senddata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.senddata);

    tokenManager = new TokenManager(getApplicationContext());

    senddata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final String usernameval=username.getText().toString();
            final String userpassval = userpass.getText().toString();


            final APIService apiService = RetroClass.getAPIService();


            Call<JWTToken> jwtTokenCall = apiService.userlogin(usernameval,userpassval);
            jwtTokenCall.enqueue(new Callback<JWTToken>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JWTToken> call, Response<JWTToken> response) {

                    JWTToken jwtToken = response.body();
                    tokenManager.createLoginSession(usernameval,jwtToken.getToken().toString());


                    Call<String> calluser = apiService.getUser(jwtToken.getToken().toString());
                    calluser.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                            showToast(""+response.body().toString());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                            showToast("inner"+t.getMessage());

                        }
                    });




                    showToast(""+jwtToken.getToken().toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<JWTToken> call, Throwable t) {

                    showToast(""+t.getMessage());
                }
            });






        }
    });



}

void showToast(String msg)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, ""+msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

**Acá puse el Token**

`   public class JWTToken {

```
@SerializedName("token")
@Expose
public String token;

public JWTToken() {
}

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}
```

}

**y acá el interface de la API**

`public interface APIService {

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/v2/tokenrequest")
Call<JWTToken> userlogin(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password")String userpass);

@GET("/v3/orchestrator/03_011A_ORCH")
Call<String> getUser(@Header("Authorization") String authorization);
```

}

`
***Si llegaste hasta acá, gracias. Hice un Debug para ver cuál es el error. Y evidentemente son los datos que paso del Postman al Android Studio.
Desde ya gracias.***

Comment: Hola!, contestaste tu propia pregunta? o me podrias resumir tu problema?

Comment: Yo diría que la Base es hasta v2/ y mírate los interceptos de retrofit ya que usar el token es algo que se puede usar muchas veces y te ahorrará lógica... cuidado también con guardar el token en sharedpreferences, deberías encriptarlo